# Can save jpegenc images with time stamp using multifilesink

Tags: gstreamer

I am trying to take snapshot from analog camera for every 10 sec, it worked fine.

**command:**

```
gst-launch-1.0 v4l2src device=/dev/video0 ! queue ! vspmfilter !
video/x-raw,width=640,height=480 ! videorate !
video/x-raw,width=640,height=480,framerate=1/10 ! jpegenc quality=30 !
multifilesink location=/home/root/images/image_%d.jpg
```

I am getting images in the specified directory like

```
image0.jpg
image1.jpg
...
```

But I want image to be saved with time stamp after every 10 sec like `image_yymmddhhmmss` for example

```
image_20180817104333.jpg
image_20180817104343.jpg
....
```

How I can achieve this with above command?

Comment: Hi, did you manage to solve this?. I'm having a similar requirement.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you could use a `pad probe` for the `multifilesink`. And whenever a buffer is received you set a new desired `location` property on the sink. Not sure though if that property can be set while in `PLAYING` state though.

Comment: Thank you for your reply,but I can't change that property while playing.

Comment: I guess you will need to use appsink then and just write the buffer data into a file by yourself.